# Simple algorithm for a sudoku solver java

Tags: java, algorithm, sudoku

I've been stuck on this thing for a while, I just can't wrap my head around it. For a homework, I have to produce an algorithm for a sudoku solver that can check what number goes in a blank square in a row, in a column and in a block. It's a regular 9x9 sudoku and I'm assuming that the grid is already printed so I have to produce the part where it solves it.

I've read a ton of stuff on the subject I just get stuck expressing it.

I want the solver to do the following:

- If the value is smaller than 9, increase it by 1
- If the value is 9, set it to zero and go back 1
- If the value is invalid, increase by 1

I've already read about backtracking and such but I'm in the early stage of the class so I'd like to keep it as simple as possible.

I'm more capable of writing in pseudo code but not so much with the algorithm itself and it's the algorithm that is needed for this exercise.

Thanks in advance for your help guys.

Comment: What class is this for?  This does not seem like an assignment for an intro to programming course, unless you are leaving out a lot of details.

Comment: Have you tried big brother (aka google)? One of the first hits brings up http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-set-7-suduku/

Comment: @mbeckish it's intro to java

Comment: @Cherry - What have you covered recently in class?  That should give you a clue regarding what type of solution they are looking for.  For example, have you covered recursion?  Backtracking algorithms?  Object Oriented design?

Comment: Are you allowed to use backtracking?

Comment: @mbeckish Honestly, we covered very little. Loops, Switch, some statements, arrays stuff like that

Comment: @rpax yeah, I don't see any instruction to says not to

Comment: @Cherry and recursion too? Backtracking is based in recursion

Comment: @Cherry - Since this is homework, I think the best advice would be for you to talk to your teacher / TA.  They should be more than happy to point you in the right direction.  As others have stated, you can easily google a solution, but then you would just be copying and pasting code, and you might not understand any of it.  All that will do is leave you confused, while fooling your teacher into believing you don't need any help.

Comment: @mbeckish I already spoke to him. It didn't do any good that's why I'm here.

Comment: @SwankSwashbucklers Programmers is a site for professional programmers discussing conceptual questions about software development.  This question does not qualify.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as it's homework, I believe I can point you in the general direction.

To start, keep a two-dimensional array (or a data structure that can represent the grid), and keep track of the values that can go there. Let's say it's a class named "possibilities":

```
public class Possibilities {

    //Keep track of the numbers possible internally, with an accessor

}
```

The way sudoku works, there will usually be a square with only a single answer (in some cases, this won't be available, which means you need to potentially make a copy of the data and play out a little bit, or have a way to roll back). Simply put, fill in the answer, and then iterate over the adjacent squares to remove the freshly put number as a possibility (And check those squares simultaneously as new potential answers).

Comment: may even want a specialty class for the sudoko grid that can assign a block a row and column number, as well as a sub-block number. That would allow easier validity checks.

Comment: @Rogue sorry for the dumb question but I can write my algorithm in actual code?

Comment: @Cherry The algorithm would more or less be a simple 1) iterate over the contents of the filled grid 2) When a single answer is found, fill it 3) iterate over the affected rows for new answers, repeat 2 if found. 4) repeat

Comment: @Rogue That algorithm will fail on any well designed puzzle. Here's an example. Let's say that a row has three empty squares and is missing numbers 1,4, and 6.  The first empty square can be 1,4, or 6. The other two squares can either be 4 or 6. Where does the 1 go? Searching for single answer squares is an optimization, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest algorithm for solving a sudoku puzzle is a complete search. That is, trying every single combination until you find one that works. The easiest way to implement this is recursively. I know you don't want to get involved in backtracking, but I actually think that would be the easiest way for you to write this algorithm.

Assume you already have an algorithm that checks whether `n` can go in some cell at `(i, j)` in your board. This means that `n` does not violate any of the constraints (there can only be one number from 1 .. 9 in each row, column and box). This should not be too hard, you just have to loop through the row, column and box that contains cell `(i, j)` and make sure that `n` does not appear yet.

Then, you will have a recursive function called `solve()` that will return true if it finds a solution, otherwise it will return false. The function will constantly place numbers in empty cells of the sudoku board (only if they don't violate the constraints, which we assume you already write an algorithm for) until it is filled. Once filled, the puzzle is solved. You know that the board is valid because you've been checking the validity of every number you place on the way there. If no number can be placed at any point, it will backtrack by returning false.

The pseudocode for solve will look something like this:

```
boolean solve()
    if the board is filled
        return true

    for each cell that is not empty
        for n = 1 .. 9
            if n does not exist in this row, column and box
                place n in this cell
                if solve()
                    return true
                remove n from this cell
    return false
```